# Choosing Window Operator for 1-D Elevation Data

Tags: elevation, filter, topography, median

Have an interesting theoretical question here: Say you have a swath of elevation data that is essentially a line of densely spaced points. The data is noisy, so a simple median filter is something I am trying to implement. Where it gets tricky is what size window to use. The points are typically 0.7 m apart, but there are gaps in the data whereby the distance between two consecutive points is much larger (100s of m to kms).

What method could I use for smoothing the topography through a median filter?